# the best way to implement readable switch case with strings in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, switch-statement

In other dynamic languages like ruby, javascript etc. you can do simply this:

```
switch(someString) {
    case "foo":
       //do something;
       break;
    case "bar":
       // do something else;
       break;
    default:
       // do something by default;
}
```

In objective-c, because it's derived very colsely from c language, you can't do that. My best practice for this is:

```
#import "CaseDemo.h"

#define foo 1
#define bar 2

static NSMutableDictionary * cases;

@implementation CaseDemo

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        if (cases == nil) {
            // this dict can be defined as a class variable
            cases = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
            [cases setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:foo] forKey:@"foo"];
            [cases setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bar] forKey:@"bar"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) switchFooBar:(NSString *) param {
    switch([[cases objectForKey:param] intValue]) {
        case foo:
            NSLog(@"its foo");
            break;
        case bar:
            NSLog(@"its bar");
            break;
        default: 
            NSLog(@"its default");
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

It's seems to be ok, but #define makes foo and bar like a reserved word, and I can't use in my code. If I replace define constants with class constants, this problem is fixed, because in other classes I must use MyClassName before the constant name. But how can I minimize the object allocation for this simple task? Someone have a "better practice" for this?

**EDIT:**
The code below is what I wanted to do, but it's a little bit unconfortable to get the values of the enum or #define. Because I created an application what have just an input where I can write the string to get that hash and go back to xcode and set the values for the enums. So my problem is I can't do that in runtime time, because of the main behavour of switch case statement... Or if I do that with that NSDictionary way -> its have a lot of overhead compared with this solution.

```
#import "CaseDemo.h"

typedef enum {
    foo = 1033772579,
    bar = -907719821
} FooBar;

unsigned int APHash(NSString* s)
{
    const char* str = [s UTF8String];
    unsigned int len = [s length];    

    unsigned int hash = 0xAAAAAAAA;
    unsigned int i    = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < len; str++, i++)
    {
        hash ^= ((i & 1) == 0) ? (  (hash <<  7) ^ (*str) * (hash >> 3)) :
        (~((hash << 11) + ((*str) ^ (hash >> 5))));
    }

    return hash;
}

@implementation CaseDemo


- (void) switchFooBar:(NSString *) param {
    switch(APHash(param)) {
        case foo:
            NSLog(@"its foo");
            break;
        case bar:
            NSLog(@"its bar");
            break;
        default: 
            NSLog(@"its default");
            break;

    }
}

@end
```

**NOTE:** the hash function can defined elsewhere in common namespace to use it anywhere, typically I create a Utils.h or Common.h for this kind of stuff.

**NOTE2:** In "real word" we need to use some cryptographic hashing function, but now I used the algorithm by Arash Partow to keep the example simple.

**So, my final question:** Is there a way to evaluate these values with the preprocessor somehow? I think no, but maybe? :-)

Something like:

```
// !!!!!! I know this code is not working, I don't want comments about "this is wrong" !!!!
// I want a solution to invoke method with preprocessor, or something like that. 
typedef enum {
        foo = APHash(@"foo"),
        bar = APHash(@"bar")
    } FooBar;
```

**UPDATE**: I found a "maybe solution" but it seems to be work with g++ 4.6> only. [generalized constant expressions](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=C%2b%2b0x:_Generalized_constant_expression_/_User-defined_literal) may be do it for me. But I'm still testing...

Comment: `@define`? Did you mean `#define`?

Comment: @epatel: I don't create benchmark but I think that the hash lookup is cheaper than string comparsion. NSMutableDictionary, I think, using hash table, because the developer documentation said: "NSDictionary is “toll-free bridged” with its Core Foundation counterpart, CFDictionary Reference". One hash lookup is cheaper than make comparsion for every string. Now I think, the only way to make my method better, that I use just a hash function to store the string values on first initialization with class variables. And i put those class variable references into the specific cases.

Comment: @epatel: I will append that example above to my question.

Comment: @epatel: Update, I can't do that because, case only works with compile time constants like c.

Comment: This idiom would be quite problematic if your int values started at 0: if you looked up a string not in `cases`, you'd get back `nil`, and `nil`'s `intValue` is 0.

Comment: Updated the question, but from this side I think enum or #define is inrelevant. They are creates compile time constants. But enum is better because you can group your constants. But both of above, i cannot find how to make compile time evals... (And its' bad because I don't no that I search solution in a wrong terms, or there is just no solution for this)

Comment: @Richard: I know but in that aspect the solution is simple:`typedef enum {
    foo = 1, 
    bar
} FooBar;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef enum {
    foo,
    bar
} FooBar;

- (void) switchFooBar:(NSString *) param {
    switch([[cases objectForKey:param] intValue]) {
        case foo:
            NSLog(@"its foo");
            break;
        case bar:
            NSLog(@"its bar");
            break;
        default: 
            NSLog(@"its default");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a string as the input to your switch method? If you use the `FooBar` enum then you avoid the dictionary altogether.

Comment: Write a function that converts the JSON string values into the Enum types.  `-(FooBar)foobarFromJsonVal:(NSString*)val{ if([val isEqualToString:@"foo"]) return foo; else return bar;  }`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * extension = [fileName pathExtension];
NSString * directory = nil;

NSUInteger index = [@[@"txt",@"png",@"caf",@"mp4"] indexOfObjectPassingTest:^
                    BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    return [obj isEqualToString:extension];
}];

switch (index)
{
    case 0:
        directory = @"texts/";
        break;
    case 1:
        directory = @"images/";
        break;
    case 2:
        directory = @"sounds/";
        break;
    case 3:
        directory = @"videos/";
        break;
    default:
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"unkonwnFileFormat"
                                       reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"zip file contain nknown file format: %@",fileName]
                                     userInfo:nil];
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique is extracted from production code and modified to use colors for this example. The premise is that a string comes in with the text name of a color from some external feed. This inbound color name is matched against known Crayola color names in the system. If the new color name matches any known Crayola color name strings, the numeric value for HTML hex code equivalent of that Crayola color name is returned.

First use http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/crc/ and put all of your known Crayola color names through it to get numerical equivalents. These will be used in the case statements. Then put those values into an enumerated for cleanliness (e.g. `LivingColors` below).  These numbers become equivalent to the actual color name string.

Then at run time the variable text is put through the same function, but internal to your code, to generate the same kind of numeric constant. If the numeric constant from the code matches the statically generated constant, then the text strings that they represent are exactly equal.

The internal code function is `crc32()` found in `zlib.h`. This generates a unique number based upon the text put through it just like the web page converter above. The unique number from `crc32()` can then be used in a common C `switch()` statement to match against the known colors which were pre-processed into numbers into the enumerated.

To use the native system function `crc32()` to generate CRC32B values, include the `/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib` in your project for linking. Be sure to include or `#import <zlib.h>` in your source that references `crc32()`

Implement an Objective C category on `NSString` to make the native `NSString` class understand the `crc32:` and `htmlColor:` messages.

Finally, read/get the name of the color into an `NSString` object, then send the string the `htmlColor:` message, it switches to match the 'strings' and returns the HTML hex equivalent value for a Crayola color name.

```
#import <zlib.h>

#define typedefEnum( enumName )               typedef enum enumName enumName; enum enumName

/**
    @see Crayola Web Colors https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_crayola.asp
    @see CRC32B value generator for static case strings http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/crc/ or http://www.md5calc.com
*/

#define typedefEnum( enumName ) typedef enum enumName enumName; enum enumName

typedefEnum( LivingColors ) {
    kRedColor                   = 0xc22c196f,    // "Red" is 0xED0A3F in HTML
    kBlueberryColor             = 0xfbefa670,    // "Blueberry" is 0x4F86F7 in HTML
    kLightChromeGreenColor      = 0x44b77242,    // "Light Chrome Green" is 0xBEE64B in HTML
    kPermanentGeraniumLakeColor = 0xecc4f3e4,    // "Permanent Geranium Lake" is 0xE12C2C in HTML
    kIlluminatingEmeraldColor   = 0x4828d5f2,    // "Illuminating Emerald" is 0x319177 in HTML
    kWildWatermelonColor        = 0x1a17c629,    // "Wild Watermelon" is 0xFD5B78 in HTML
    kWashTheDogColor            = 0xea9fcbe6,    // "Wash the Dog" is 0xFED85D in HTML
    kNilColor                   = 0xDEADBEEF     // could use '0' but what fun is that?
};


// generates the CRC32B, same used to check each ethernet packet on the network you receive so it’s fast
- (NSUInteger) crc32 {
    NSUInteger theResult;

    theResult = (NSUInteger)crc32(  0L,
                                    (const unsigned char *) [self UTF8String],
                                    (short)self.length);

    return theResult;
}

/// @return the HTML hex value for a recognized color name string.
- (NSUInteger) htmlColor {
    NSUInteger      theResult               = 0x0;
    LivingColors    theColorInLivingColor   = kNilColor;

    theColorInLivingColor = (LivingColors) [self crc32];
     // return the HTML value for a known color by effectively switching on a string.
    switch ( theColorInLivingColor ) {

        case kRedColor : {
            theResult = 0xED0A3F;
        }
            break;

        case kBlueberryColor : {
            theResult = 0x4F86F7;
        }
            break;

        case kLightChromeGreenColor : {
            theResult = 0xBEE64B;
        }
            break;

        case kPermanentGeraniumLakeColor : {
            theResult = 0xE12C2C;
        }
            break;

        case kIlluminatingEmeraldColor : {
            theResult = 0x319177;
        }
            break;

        case kWildWatermelonColor : {
            theResult = 0xFD5B78;
        }
            break;

        case kWashTheDogColor : {
            theResult = 0xFED85D;
        }
            break;

        case kNilColor :
        default : {
            theResult = 0x0;
        }
            break;

    }

    return theResult;
}
```

For the example an Objective C Category was made to add the two methods  the existing Cocoa class `NSString`, rather than subclass it.

The end result is that an `NSString` object *appears* to have the ability to natively get a CRC32B value of itself (very handy beyond this example) and can essentially `switch(`) on the color’s name string that possibly came in from the user, a text file, etc. to identify a match much faster than any text string comparison can occur.

Fast, efficient, and reliable, this approach can easily be adapted to any kind of variable text matching to static known value text. Bear in mind that CRC32B checksums are generated by bitwise operations and the C switch statement use bitwise operations optimized at compile time. Remember this is speedy because CRC32B is the highly optimized function used to check each ethernet packet your Mac/iPhone/iPad receives... even when you download multi-gigabyte files like macOS Sierra.