# Creating an app that defines a set of data based on several criteria

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create an iPhone app that takes the user's response to four criteria and, based on that, shows a specific set of data related to that permutation of answers. For example, in the main view controller:

User selects A or B in a segmented controller (let's say they choose A)

User selects C or D in a segmented controller (they choose D)

User selects E or F in a segmented controller (they choose E)

User inputs an age in a text box (they type in 37)

User touches the "Get Numbers" button

Based on the combination of "A, D, E, 37", the view that appears on the touch of "Get Numbers" shows an image overlaid with seven labels containing the numbers 17.1, 14.2, 30.0, 60.4, 18.1, 19.7 and 80.2. If the user had selected a different set of responses on the main controller, a different set of numbers would appear in those same labels.

I've researched the various elements, but I can't figure out how to combine them to produce the desired outcome. How can I do this?  Any advice would be much appreciated--I'm quite new to xCode and completely stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not actually program in Xcode or Objective-C, but it seems to me that you are looking for a CASE statement.  I found the following links, I hope they help:

[the best way to implement readable switch case with strings in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088212/the-best-way-to-implement-readable-switch-case-with-strings-in-objective-c)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, this is all contained in one viewController so you shouldn't need to pass a bunch of properties. The hard part is knowing how you are attempting to mutate the values and how much branching needs to happen. Also, you have 7 return values and there's no way of knowing how to compute these, like if the output from the first response is calculated with the second and third responses, etc.
EDIT, after reading your comment:

There are 8 possible outcomes, maybe you can create 8 methods to deal with each one. I can't think of any other way, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
Possible values: 
{ 
  (A,C,E) ;
  (B,C,E) ; 
  (A,D,E) ; 
  (B,D,E) ; 
  (A,C,F) ; 
  (B,C,F) ; 
  (A,D,F) ; 
  (B,D,F) ;
}

//Do it with an IF statement:
//first capture state into BOOL values
BOOL a = NO;
BOOL c = NO;
BOOL e = NO;
if (abSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { a = YES; }
if (cdSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { c = YES; }
if (efSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { e = YES; }

//next do some matching with IF statements
if (a && c && e) {
    //do something for A,C,E
}
if (!a && c && e) {
    //do something for B,C,E
}
if (a && !c && e) {
    //do something for A,D,E
} 
if (!a && !c && e) {
    //do something for B,D,E
}
if (a && c && !e) {
    //do something for A,C,F
}
if (!a && c && !e) {
    //do something for B,C,F
}
if (a && !c && !e) {
    //do something for A,D,F
}            
if (!a && !c && !e) {
    //do something for B,D,F
}
```

If you have hardcoded values you can just write the label updating text inside each IF block that matches your requirements. It's hacky but it's all I can think of right now

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think the values actually need to be computed, just typed into the labels--almost as strings, really. They exist already for every possible combination of the choices; it's a matter of plugging in the corresponding values when the user selects a particular combination, if that makes sense.  All four responses are required to get the corresponding values.

Comment: I just updated my answer. There are 8 possible outcomes.

Comment: Appreciate the update. I was thinking that if statements would be the way to go, but I couldn't visualize it. This is quite helpful.